# How do i access paintcomponent graphics g variable to draw things from other methods?

Tags: java, swing

I have these classes, but, what i'm trying to do is access the paintcomponents graphics2d variable from other methods to draw things, but i cant access it because i don't know how to, please tell me how to, heres the classes

Debug (the main class)

```
import java.awt.Color;

import flarebird.Window;
import flarebird.game3d.Renderer;
import flarebird.game3d.drawables.Line;

public class Debug {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Window test = new Window(800, 600, 100, 10, true, "This is the title");
        test.displayProperties();
        
        Renderer renderer = new Renderer(true);
        test.addRenderer(renderer);
        
        Line line = new Line(100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 2, new Color(100, 100, 0));
        renderer.draw(line);
        
    }

}
```

Window (the class the make the window):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import flarebird.game3d.Renderer;

public class Window {

    
    static int width;
    static int height;
    static int x;
    static int y;
    static boolean v;
    static String title;
    
    public Window() {}
    
    public Window(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, int X, int Y, boolean V, String TITLE) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        width = WIDTH;
        height = HEIGHT;
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        v = V;
        title = TITLE;
        
        
    }
    
    // Window Variable
    public static JFrame window = new JFrame();
    
    /**
     * 
     * 
     * window.setVisible(v);
     * Sets the window visible or not depending on the boolean
     * 
     * 
    */
    
    // setVisible method
    public void setWindowVisible(boolean v) {
        
        window.setVisible(v);
        
    }

    
    
    
    /**
     * 
     * 
     * window.setWindowSize(); 
     * Sets the size of the window
     * 
     * 
     */
    
    // setWindowSize method
    public void setWindowSize(int Width, int Height) {
        
        window.setSize(Width, Height);
        
    }
    /**
     * 
     * 
     * window.setWindowLocation(x, y);
     * Sets the location of the window
     * 
     * 
    */
    // setWindowLocation method
    public void setWindowLocation(int X, int Y) {
        
        window.setLocation(X, Y);
        
    }
    /**
     * 
     * 
     * window.setTitle(TITLE);
     * Sets the title of the window
     * 
     * 
    */
    // setTitle method
    public void setWindowTitle(String TITLE) {
        
        window.setTitle(TITLE);
        
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * window.displayWindow();
     * displays the window to the screen
     * 
     */
    // displayWindow method
    
    public void displayProperties() {
        
        try {

        window.setSize(width, height);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocation(x, y);
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.setVisible(v);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public void addRenderer(Renderer renderer) {
        try {
            
            window.getContentPane().add(renderer.renderPanel);
            
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Line (the class for the line constructor):

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Line {
    private int x1;
    private int y1;
    private int z1;
    private int x2;
    private int y2;
    private int z2;
    private int scale;
    private Color rgb;
    double scale2;
    
    public Line(int X1, int Y1, int Z1, int X2, int Y2, int Z2, double SCALE, Color RGB) {
        
        this.x1 = X1;
        this.y1 = Y1;
        this.z1 = Z1;
        
        this.x2 = X2;
        this.y2 = Y2;
        this.z2 = Z2;
        
        this.scale2 = SCALE;
        this.scale2 = (int) Math.round(this.scale2);
        this.scale = (int) this.scale2;
        
        this.rgb = RGB;
        
        
        
    }

    public int getX1() {
        return x1;
    }

    public void setX1(int x1) {
        this.x1 = x1;
    }

    public int getY1() {
        return y1;
    }

    public void setY1(int y1) {
        this.y1 = y1;
    }

    public int getZ1() {
        return z1;
    }

    public void setZ1(int z1) {
        this.z1 = z1;
    }

    public int getX2() {
        return x2;
    }

    public void setX2(int x2) {
        this.x2 = x2;
    }

    public int getY2() {
        return y2;
    }

    public void setY2(int y2) {
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public int getZ2() {
        return z2;
    }

    public void setZ2(int z2) {
        this.z2 = z2;
    }

    public int getScale() {
        return scale;
    }

    public void setScale(int scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public Color getRgb() {
        return rgb;
    }

    public void setRgb(Color rgb) {
        this.rgb = rgb;
    }
    
}
```

Renderer (the class to draw things):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import flarebird.Window;
import flarebird.game3d.drawables.Line;

public class Renderer {

    private boolean enableAntiAlias;
    
    public Renderer() {
        
        
    }
    
    public Renderer(boolean enableAntiAliasing) {
        
        this.enableAntiAlias = enableAntiAliasing;
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public JPanel renderPanel = new JPanel() {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            
                try {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                
                int WindowWidth = Window.window.getWidth();
                int WindowHeight = Window.window.getHeight();
                
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                class Camera extends JPanel /*implements Runnable, KeyListener, MouseWheelListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener*/ {
    
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        int test = 0;
                        for (;;) {
                            
                            
                            test++;
                            System.out.println("" + test);
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                
                if (enableAntiAlias) {
                    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                }
                
                g2d.setColor(Color.PINK);
                g2d.drawLine(0*WindowWidth/1, 0*WindowHeight/1, 300+WindowWidth/5, 300+WindowHeight/5);
            
            }
            
                
            catch (Exception e) {
                
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e);
                
            }
            
            
        }
    };
    
    public void draw(Line line) {
        
            Graphics g;
            renderPanel.?.setColor(line.getRgb());
            renderPanel.?.drawLine((line.getX1()+line.getZ1()*line.getScale()), (line.getY1()+line.getZ1()*line.getScale()), (line.getX2()+line.getZ2()*line.getScale()), (line.getY2()+line.getZ2())*line.getScale());
            
            
    }
    
}
```

Comment: *please tell me how to,* - you don't. Custom painting is done in the paintComponent() method or you invoke a method directly from the paintComponent() method and pass the Graphics object to that method. What is that try/catch block doing in the paintComponent() method.? Why are you defining a class in the method. Get rid of that code. Also, you should NOT be referencing external classes in the paintComponent() method. The painting method should only know or care about itself. You can use the getWidth() or getHeight() methods to get the current size of the panel.

Comment: If you want to draw Line objects. then you can use an ArrayList and add the Line object to the ArrayList. Then in the paintComponent() method you iterate through the ArrayList to paint each Line object. Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of this approach.

Comment: sorry for the mess, i didn't clean up my code, but thanks for the reply anyways

Comment: and the reason why i use alot of try/catches is because i'm a safe person and make sure every potential error is shown

Comment: **"**_make sure every potential error is shown_**"** you may want to use `assert`